# Play Framework application never stops when calling DefaultApplicationLifecycle.stop

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I am developing a cluster application based on Akka/Play where the Frontend node can get quarantined by the cluster. In such cases, I want to exit the Play application so that it can be restarted and rejoin the cluster.

I read on various places that the right way to gracefully stop a play application was to use the `ApplicationLifecycle`. I am using dependency injection to get a `DefaultApplicationLifecycle` object and call `defaultApplicationLifecycle.stop()` whenever a `ThisActorSystemQuarantinedEvent` occurs.

My problem is that the application ends up in a strange state where the app still runs and listens on the HTTP port, but almost nothing is working (all actors seem dead). It seems the `Future` is never completed while I define no `stopHook` in my application. Should I force to call `System.exit()` at some point?

Comment: It looks like all `DefaultApplicationLifecycle#stop` does is run all of the stop hooks. You would need to handle actual process on your own. If the future never completes, it's likely because one of the stop hooks failed to complete for some reason (not because none were added), though it's hard to say which or why.

Answer (score 3):

`ApplicationLifecycle` is used to register hooks that are executed when your application stops. It is not supposed to be used to stop the application however. From the [docs](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle):

> This is used to hook into Play lifecycle events, specifically, when Play is stopped.
>
> ...
>
> Stop hooks are executed when the application is shutdown, in reverse from when they were registered. Due to this reverse ordering, a component can know that it is safe to use the components it depends on as long as it hasn't received a shutdown event.

What you really want is a `Application` instance. From [`Application.stop` docs](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Application):

> Stop the application. The returned future will be redeemed when all stop hooks have been run.

When `Application.stop` is called, then all the hooks register in `ApplicationLifecycle` are executed in "reverse from when they were registered". You can get an `Application` instance using Dependency Injection too:

```
class SomeClass @Inject() (app: Application) {
    def somethingHappensThatRequireApplicationToStop() = app.stop()
}
```

You are still able to receive requests because you just stopped the application, but not the `Server`. Not completely sure about it, but I think you can inject it just the way you injected the app above:

```
import play.core.server.Server

class SomeClass @Inject() (app: Application, server: Server) {
    def somethingHappensThatRequireApplicationToStop() = {
        app.stop()
        server.stop()
    }   
}
```

Also, since it stopping the server forces an app stop, you just need the following:

```
import play.core.server.Server

class SomeClass @Inject() (server: Server) {
    def somethingHappensThatRequireToStop() = {
        server.stop()
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I just wonder why the future of my defaultApplication lifecycle is never called :S. I will try what you suggest, thanks !

Comment: Actually I see the exact same behavior: the app stays in a stale state. I wonder how to debug the fact that the app never really stops.

Comment: I miss a detail of your question. See my edits about how to also stop the server.

Comment: It seems the server cannot be injected like that, I am trying to see how to access it.

Comment: On injection and testing, @marcospereira, can you take a look at a similar issue I have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924057/how-to-test-a-play-application-that-extends-a-custom-trait