# How to Test a Play Application that extends a custom trait

Tags: scala, testing, dependency-injection, playframework, specs2

I'm having trouble writing tests for a mixin to my Play application that runs in it's own thread separate from play. I've tried over-writing `WithApplication.provideApplication` method with no luck. I get an `inheriting conflicting methods` error. (one from the real app "MyRunnableSystemWrapper", one from my *mocked* fake mixin called "MyMockedSystemWrapper").

`execute(system)` runs my system that is tested elsewhere and has sideaffects (connects to networked services, thus failing this test when such things are not available. Good news is I have a mocked service of my system wrapper that uses a system which does NOT have side affects and DB/Network calls are mocked out. However I do not know how to give THIS MOCKED version of my app to "WithApplication" test.

Reduced Code for clarity:

```
class Application extends Controller with MyRunnableSystemWrapper {

  val pool: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
  val system = new MyRunnableSystem() //system is abstract in MRSW ^^^ above
  pool.execute(system)

  def index = Action {
    OK("HI")
  }
}
```

My Test:

```
class MyAppTest(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv) extends Specification  {

  abstract class WithMyMockApp extends WithApplication {
    def provideApplication = new controllers.Application with MyMockedSystemWrapper // This imports MyRunnableSystemWrapper 

  }

  "Sending a GET request" should {
    "Respond with OK" in new WithMyMockApp {
      val response = route(app, FakeRequest(GET, "/")).get
      status(response) mustEqual OK
    }
  }
}
```

If I'm not running my Runnable in the correct place and should be calling it somewhere else to make this testing easier, let me know!

Comment: I've also thought about creating a self-type reference of my system like so: `class Application extends controller { mysys : MySystem => ...} ` however I do not know how to let Play know to use a certain dependency. Since play automatically find this Application Controller and starts it, how do I give it my Mixin in Prod and in Test?

Comment: I get a `com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision` Error because Play doesn't know how to start it with MySystem.

Answer (score 0):

You could inject your system wrapper instead of extending it

```
trait SystemWrapper {
    def execute(system: RunnableSystem)
}

class MyRunnableSystemWrapper extends SystemWrapper {...}
class MyMockedSystemWrapper extends SystemWrapper {...}

class Application @Inject() (systemWrapper SystemWrapper) extends Controller {
```

Then you need to tell Guice which implementation of `SystemWrapper` you want for runtime and which one for test. One way of doing this is by using different Guice modules for runtime/test which you set in your `.conf` files.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for but you lost me at .conf. Do you have an example of .conf. I've already setup a test.conf and it is in use during test. Thanks!

Comment: You can see here how to create a module and then in each `.conf` file choose what module to load https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Play-libraries

Comment: I get a `No implementation for com.echostar.sse.meteor.models.Meteor.SystemComponent was bound.` when I tried the Inject way: 

`class prodSystem extends MeteorSystemComponent { rmqServiceFactory: RMQServiceFactory =>
  val system = new MeteorSystem("Production")
}

class Application @Inject() (msc: Meteor.SystemComponent) extends Controller with Logging {`

I named it prodSystem for now. According to the error message, it's not binding. how do I bind the two?

Comment: You can do that in a Guice module that you then enable in your .conf file: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#programmatic-bindings